# Is there any way to call typescript methods inside Jquery event handler inside ngAfterViewInit method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `Angular 4` . Want to call methods of typescript file from `ngAfterViewInit` method like

```
 declare var  $;
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-details',
 templateUrl: './details.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})    
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit ,AfterViewInit{
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(document).on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
         //this.setValueInsideDetailForm(); This is methods inside typescript file , which one i want to call
     });
    }
  setValueInsideDetailForm(){
       // Some code here.
   }

}
```

But it throws error like `setValueInsideDetailForm` is undefined.

Comment: use arrow function for the handler to keep the same context

Comment: Using JQuery with Angular is an anti-pattern : you should not handle DOM events yourself. Instead, use a library implementing bootstrap for Angular, such as **[this one](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)**.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(document).on("hide.bs.modal", () => {
        this.setValueInsideDetailForm();
    });
}
```

You need to use an arrow function to be able to access a method outside of the current scope.

```
myFirstMethod() {
  console.log('my first method');
}

myMethod() {
  this.myFirstMethod() // Works

  function test() {
     this.myFirstMethod() // Does not work because it is restricted to what 
                             is inside of the test() method
  }

  const test = () => {
    this.myFirstMethod() // Works since is not restricted to test method 
                            scope
  }

}
```

Comment: Explain your solution. It can be considered as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is taking `this` context from your component. Before the `$` type `const self = this;` and use `self` instead.

Try logging `this` inside your callback function and see what it logs.

Comment: Doing this is a bad behavior. It keeps a reference to `this` with the variable `self` as long as the event handler exists => It creates memory leaks.

Comment: You can just dereference it `self = null;`

Comment: It's right but it's better to use `arrow function` to ensure that the context of `this` is preserved.